# Combine DustJS size helper and select

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I have an array of messages and I want to use a select to vary some descriptive text, utilizing the size helper:

```
 {@select key="{@size key=messages/}"}
     {@eq value="1"}only 1{/eq}
     {@default}More than 1!{/default}
 {/select}
```

This doesn't compile.  What's wrong here?

I know I could probably more simply use $len to simplify this, but I'm more curious about how to combine dust helpers.  Or if that's even possible.

Comment: Using a Dust helper as the parameter of another Dust helper isn't possible. Sorry.

Comment: @smfoote Thanks for the intel!  I'll reapproach.  If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dust grammar doesn't allow for Dust helpers to be used as parameters inside other helpers. In fact, the grammar doesn't allow for Dust helpers to be used as parameters anywhere.

Comment: @abernier it depends on your situation. It is possible to add the output of a helper to the context, then reference that output using the normal `{reference}` syntax.